# Obtener las cantidades posibles de articulos - Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Llevo varios días tratando con el siguiente problema, el cual solo he tenido un avance no muy bueno, el problema es el siguiente:

Estoy desarrollando un programa que me ayude a obtener el conjunto de cantidades que deban tener ciertos artículos, que al ser multiplicado por su precio y sumado el resultado de cada uno de los artículos, me de una suma total **entre 38,000 y 42,000.**

Les detallo un poco mas, suponiendo que tengo 3 artículos Ejemplo:

**Martillo**: 1,300 | **Lampara** 1,800 | **Pintura**: 900. Donde el numero del lado es el precio del articulo.

Si por ejemplo al **martillo** le ponemos una cantidad de **20** y a **lampara** una cantidad de **5** y a **Pintura** una cantidad de **5** y multiplicamos la cantidad del articulo por su precio y todos los resultados los sumamos, nos da 39,500 (Dentro del rango que quiero).

Bueno ese es el problema, y necesito que el programa lo haga por mi, pero que me saque todas las posibles cantidades que pueden tener cada grupo de artículos para que me de en el rango que quiero.

Hasta ahora he logrado muy poco, dejare por aquí el código que tengo, que la verdad no es el mejor, y esta hecho a groso modo. Aquí el código:

> EDIT: EDITE EL CÓDIGO PARA QUE SEA MAS CLARO

```
package main;

public class Ejecucion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        producto producto1 = new producto(1300);
        producto producto2 = new producto(1520);

        int i = 0;
        while(i < 10000){
             double calculo = (producto1.getPrecio()* producto1.getCantidad()) + (producto2.getPrecio()*producto2.getCantidad());
             if(calculo > 38000 && calculo < 42000){
                System.out.println("Cantidad posible "+ producto1.getCantidad()+","+producto2.getCantidad());
                System.out.println("Cantidad posible "+ producto1.getCantidad()+","+producto2.getCantidad());
                //incrementar variable de cantidad para que siga rrecorriendo las posiblidades

                producto1.setCantidad();// 
            }else{
                producto1.setCantidad();
            }

            //evaluar si da una cantidad mas grande para empezar con otro calculo
            if(producto1.getPrecio()*producto1.getCantidad() > 42000){
                //reiniciar la cantidad del producto 1 para volver a contar
                //con el nuevo indice que se le dara a producto2
                producto1.resetCantidad();
                //incrementa
                producto2.setCantidad();
            }           

            i++;
        }
    }
}

class producto{

    private int precio;
    private int cantidad;

    public producto(int precio){
        this.precio = precio;
        this.cantidad = 1;
    }

    public void setCantidad(){
        this.cantidad++;
    }

    public int getCantidad(){
        return this.cantidad;
    }

    public int getPrecio(){
        return this.precio;
    }

    //Vuelve la cantidad del objeto en 1
    public void resetCantidad(){
        this.cantidad = 1;
    }
}
```

Vale se que hay otras formas de hacer este mismo código.

Como se darán cuenta aquí solo pude lograr obtener cantidades posibles de dos artículos, y con un codigo no adecuado diria yo.
Aqui el output que me arroja al ejecutarlo:

> Cantidad posible 29,1 Cantidad posible 30,1 Cantidad posible 31,1
>   Cantidad posible 27,2 Cantidad posible 28,2 Cantidad posible 29,2
>   Cantidad posible 26,3 Cantidad posible 27,3 Cantidad posible 28,3
>   Cantidad posible 25,4 Cantidad posible 26,4 Cantidad posible 27,4
>   Cantidad posible 24,5 Cantidad posible 25,5 Cantidad posible 26,5
>   Cantidad posible 23,6 Cantidad posible 24,6 Cantidad posible 25,6
>   Cantidad posible 22,7 Cantidad posible 23,7 Cantidad posible 24,7
>   Cantidad posible 20,8 Cantidad posible 21,8 Cantidad posible 22,8
>   Cantidad posible 19,9 Cantidad posible 20,9 Cantidad posible 21,9
>   Cantidad posible 18,10 Cantidad posible 19,10 Cantidad posible 20,10
>   Cantidad posible 17,11 Cantidad posible 18,11 Cantidad posible 19,11
>   Cantidad posible 16,12 Cantidad posible 17,12 Cantidad posible 18,12
>   Cantidad posible 15,13 Cantidad posible 16,13 Cantidad posible 17,13
>   Cantidad posible 13,14 Cantidad posible 14,14 Cantidad posible 15,14
>   Cantidad posible 12,15 Cantidad posible 13,15 Cantidad posible 14,15
>   Cantidad posible 11,16 Cantidad posible 12,16 Cantidad posible 13,16
>   Cantidad posible 10,17 Cantidad posible 11,17 Cantidad posible 12,17
>   Cantidad posible 9,18 Cantidad posible 10,18 Cantidad posible 11,18
>   Cantidad posible 8,19 Cantidad posible 9,19 Cantidad posible 10,19
>   Cantidad posible 6,20 Cantidad posible 7,20 Cantidad posible 8,20
>   Cantidad posible 5,21 Cantidad posible 6,21 Cantidad posible 7,21
>   Cantidad posible 4,22 Cantidad posible 5,22 Cantidad posible 6,22
>   Cantidad posible 3,23 Cantidad posible 4,23 Cantidad posible 5,23
>   Cantidad posible 2,24 Cantidad posible 3,24 Cantidad posible 4,24
>   Cantidad posible 1,25 Cantidad posible 2,25 Cantidad posible 3,25
>   Cantidad posible 1,26

Pero el problema viene cuando tengo que evaluar 3 cantidades o mas. Y es que el numero de artículos no esta definido, pueden ser 2 o hasta 10. Así que no se darle solución.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como darle solución? Se lo agradeciese mucho la verdad.

Un saludo!!

Answer (score 2):

El código es muy mejorable, sobretodo para que sea más entendible. Además, la sentencia del IF está mal construida y quizá por ese motivo los cálculos no són correctos.

Yo haría lo siguiente:

```
package main;

public class Ejecucion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        producto producto1 = new producto(1300);
        producto producto2 = new producto(1520);

        int i = 0;
        while(i < 10000){
             double calculo = (producto1.getPrecio()* producto1.getCantidad()) + (producto2.getPrecio()*producto2.getCantidad());
             if(calculo > 38000 && calculo < 42000){
                System.out.println("Cantidad posible "+ producto1.getCantidad()+","+producto2.getCantidad());
                System.out.println("Cantidad posible "+ producto1.getCantidad()+","+producto2.getCantidad());
                //incrementar variable de cantidad para que siga rrecorriendo las posiblidades

                producto1.setCantidad();// 
            }else{
                producto1.setCantidad();
            }

            //evaluar si da una cantidad mas grande para empezar con otro calculo
            if(producto1.getPrecio()*producto1.getCantidad() > 42000){
                //reiniciar la cantidad del producto 1 para volver a contar
                //con el nuevo indice que se le dara a producto2
                producto1.resetCantidad();
                //incrementa
                producto2.setCantidad();
            }           

            i++;
        }
    }
}

class producto{

    private int precio;
    private int cantidad;

    public producto(int precio){
        this.precio = precio;
        this.cantidad = 1;
    }

    public void setCantidad(){
        this.cantidad++;
    }

    public int getCantidad(){
        return this.cantidad;
    }

    public int getPrecio(){
        return this.precio;
    }

    //Vuelve la cantidad del objeto en 1
    public void resetCantidad(){
        this.cantidad = 1;
    }
}
```

Fíjate que he abstraido el cálculo en una variable llamada "calculo" para que en el if sea más entendible (además, en el if repetías la operación 2 veces, cosa bastante absurda...).

Comment: Gracias ferran ahora edito la pregunta con tu codigo para que sea mas clara.